# How can I convert a value in cents to a dollar value

Tags: coldfusion

When I capture my data I am saving the value in cents so $10.00 would be 1000

When I display the value again I want to display it like 10.00
I have tried various different ways like:

```
#decimalformat(itemprice)#
#NumberFormat(itemprice, '9.99')#
#LSCurrencyFormat(itemprice, "none")#
#DollarFormat(itemprice)#
```

But every time I end up with 1000.00

Is there any way in ColdFusion to achieve this or should I rather be saving the value in dollars instead of cents and then convert it to cents where needed?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Downvoting due to this being an Arithmetic 101 issue, not a ColdFusion one.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Saving the itemprice in cents is a better idea than storing in dollars and cents.  The former allows you to use an integer datatype which is easier to work with and less prone to math errors than floats.

Comment: @DanBracuk however this is precisely why RDBMSes have MONEY columns. It deals with this for you.

Comment: Some database engines do, others don't.  Dave didn't specify his.

Comment: itemPrice / [2/SEC(¶/3)•[lim x→0 x^3+8x+10]^2]/[lim θ→0 sinθ/θ] will work.

Comment: @DanBracuk - It may not *literally* be named "money", but that does not mean a dbms does not have a fixed numeric type suitable for storing currency (unlike float). Decimal/numeric are core ansi sql types. So any standard database will support them.  Even MS Access supports it for cripes sake ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
<cfdump var="#DollarFormat(itemprice/100)#"><cfabort>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tushar I did not even think of that!

Comment: I refuse to upvote this answer because...well....this question should not have needed to be asked.

Comment: @ScottStroz, Your choice. I thought this was the case of tired mind trying to find complex solution and refusing to see the easy one.

Comment: I thought it was a case of someone pulling my leg. There is no 'complex' solution for taking a value for 'cents' and turning it into 'dollars'.